# Show that these vectors lie in a common two-dimensional plane,

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How could I show that 4 vectors $v_1, ... v_4$ lie in a common two-dimensional plane in $R^4$?

This plane $P$ does not contain the origin.

The vectors are:

$v_1=(3,0,1,4)$

$v_2=(3, 2, -1, 6)$

$v_3=(3,1,0,5)$

$v_4=(2,0, -1,1)$

I also want to find a description of $P$ using two linear equalities:

$$P = \{\vec x: f(\vec x) =a ,g(\vec x)=b\}$$

where $f$ and $g$ are linear functionals $f(\vec x) = f_1x_1 + ... f_4x_4$ and so on.

I have tried putting the 4 vectors into a 4x4 matrix and row-reduced it a few times, both times confirming that this matrix has rank 3, so that doesn't seem to help me.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: So what are $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$?

Comment: Hi @user160738, I just edited my question to include the vectors.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can treat one of the vectors like the origin and show that the differences span a two-dimensional subspace.

So, we can arbitrarily pick $v_4$ as our frame of reference. Now we get three difference vectors 
\begin{align*}
d_1 &= v_1 - v_4 \\
d_2 &= v_2 - v_4 \\
d_3 &= v_3 - v_4, \\
\end{align*}

and want to show that they span a two-dimensional subspace. You can use whatever technique you like, at this point: Row reducing a matrix, or by expressing $d_3$ as a linear combination of $d_1$ and $d_2$, probably among other possibilities.

If you can express this translated subspace as $\{d : f^*(d) = 0 = g^*(d)\}$ using linear functionals $f^*$ and $g^*$, I *believe* the original plane will be given by $\{v : f^*(v) = f^*(v_4),\ \ g^*(v) = g^*(v_4)\}$, although I haven't thought about that before.

Comment: Hi @pjs36, if I row-reduce I should find that the matrix has rank 2.  Then where can I go from there?  Pick out a basis,  probably.  Then what should I do with the third and final vector?  Should I show that it fulfills a matrix equation $Ax=b$?  I wouldn't have a 4x4 matrix, though, with my 2 basis vectors...what do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: *If* you found it had rank two, then you could say that the original four vectors were contained in a two-dimensional (affine) plane; you wouldn't need to touch the individual vectors until you wanted to find those functionals (which is something I don't recall at the moment!).

Comment: Ooh @pjs36, so I row-reduced the three difference vectors and found it had rank two, I know that where the pivots are indicates which columns from the original matrix of difference vectors are basis vectors (linearly independent).  Then, I immediately see that the non-basis vector (it happened to be the second difference vector) is a scalar-multiple of the first difference vector and so they are co-linear vectors.  I think from here I can conclude that the 4 vectors are co-planar.  Fixing one vector as a frame of reference or like an origin is sort of tricky to grasp...

Comment: Hi @pjs36, I have a silly question:  how would we know that the vector we fixed as a frame of reference...will be on this two-dimensional plane, too?  I plane around with it, and used it to row-reduce against the two basis vectors for the plane, but got rank 3 - which is weird, because it *should* be a linear combination of the basis vectors if it lies on the plane, and so the reduced matrix should have rank 2 ...

Comment: @User001 intermittently responding while grading, hence the delay. Anyway, my linear algebra is a bit rusty, so I'm mostly thinking geometrically (read: row reduction confusion!). Pick a set you can visualize to see what's happening. Say, $(1,0,1),\ (0,1,1),\ (1,1,1)$ and $(0,0,1)$ in $\Bbb R^3$. They all lie on the plane $z = 1$, and their differences are a linearly dependent set spanning the $xy$-plane. That's the intuition.

Comment: Ok got it -- thanks so much for your help, @pjs36.  Have fun grading :-)

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to show that the three vectors $v_2-v_1, v_3-v_1,v_4-v_1$ lie in the some two-dimensional plane (containing the origin). This is equivalent to the three vectors being linearly dependent:
$$a(v_2-v_1)+b(v_3-v_1)+c(v_4-v_1)=0.$$

Supposing that this translated plane is not one-dimensional, we may WLOG assume $v_2-v_1$ and $v_3-v_1$ are not scalar multiples of each other. Using Gram-Schmidt, we can find unit vectors $w$ and $w'$ that are orthogonal to each other and to everything in our plane. Then, our translated plane can be written as $\{v \mid w^\top v = w'^\top v= 0\}$. Then, translating back, our original plane is $\{v \mid w^\top v = w'^\top v = w^\top v_1\}$.

---

In your case, $v_2-v_1 = (0,2,0,2)$, $v_3-v_1=(0,1,-1,1)$, and $v_4-v_1 = (-1,0,-2,-3)$, which spans three dimensions, so unfortunately your original vectors do not lie in the same two-dimensional plane.

Comment: Thanks so much @angryavian :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach. Find the plane $P$ containing $v_1, v_2, v_3$ (this is guaranteed to exist); let $w$ be its normal vector. Now look at $(v_1-v_4)\cdot w$. If this equals zero, then $(v_1-v_4)\perp w$;  if you draw a picture, you can see why this means $v_4$ lies in $P$.

---

Basically, what we're doing is using the geometric fact that $v_1, . . . , v_4$ are coplanar iff there is a vector $w$ which is perpendicular to each of the pairwise differences $v_i-v_j$. Note that this means it's actually *equivalent*, mathematically, to the other answers; but you might find it a little more concrete (or not; YMMV).

Comment: Hi @NoahSchweber, so in three dimensions it takes two vectors to determine a plane but in four dimensions it takes three vectors to determine a hyperplane? Thanks,

Comment: @User001 I'd say instead that it takes *three points* to determine a plane, four to determine a hyperplane, etc. With two vectors, you always get a plane containing the origin.

Comment: Ah, right, @NoahSchweber. In this problem statement, the plane $P$ is specified as not containing the origin...

Comment: You're missing my point - I'm saying that the phrase "two vectors determine a plane" is only true if we're restricting attention to planes containing the origin. So, especially  in this case, it's not how you want to picture things.

Comment: Hi @NoahSchweber, I just want to discuss this a little bit more before moving on, since I agree that learning the orthogonality argument to this problem would be a great idea.  However, there's a slight problem:  I have no problem with computing plane equations in $R^3$, since we have the cross-product to utilize and we can find the normal vector with trivial computations.

Comment: But, how do we find the plane $P$ containing $v_1, v_2, v_3$ ... and a normal vector $w$ ... *without* the cross-product to use?  Pjs36's solution seems to be the one to remember, in order to not get too confused by working in 4 dimensions and overthinking this, but I would love to hear your thoughts about how to compute the plane equation.  (Unless you mean exactly what pjs36 is referring to?)  Thanks @NoahSchweber,

Comment: I was assuming you had the cross product (or the general formula for the plane containing three points) to work with.

Comment: Ooh, ok, so I must use the general formula.  I'll read up on the generalized cross-product, too. I  think the general plane equation is something like $P = \vec u + a\vec v + b \vec w$, with $\vec u$ as the base point of reference.  Thanks so much @NoahSchweber,